# Invalid route name for GET and POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through an older tutorial that was done for Rails 3. I'm using Rails 4.1.4.

One of the instructions is to change the routes file to include the following:

```
get '/boards/:board_id/conversations/:id/reply' => "conversations#reply", :as => :reply_board_conversation
post '/boards/:board_id/conversations/:id/reply' => "conversations#save_reply", :as => :reply_board_conversation
```

Obviously that gives me an error:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'reply_board_conversation'
```

It seems to me that the route is somehow trying to replicate the behaviour of a new and create action. Get for new and Post for create with a single route.
The problem is I can't figure out how to rewrite the route so it works. I've googled for solutions but can't seem to find anything. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only issue is with the duplicated "named route" name `reply_board_conversation`. So you could simply change one. I'd probably rename the save version to `save_reply_board_conversation`. Then it should work. Just remember to refer to the route this way in the future. This would primarily be used in a form tag. So, for exmaple:

```
<= form_tag :url => save_reply_board_conversation_path do %>
```

Note the use of `save_reply_board_conversation_path` instead of `reply_board_conversation_path` given that the form would be submitting a POST request instead of a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

The names for these routes should be different although since the composition of the URL is the same so you really only need a name for the first one.

The trick with named routes is they generate the URL only, they do not set the HTTP request method. That has to be done independently.

That means you can call the same named route two different ways:

```
<%= link_to('View', board_path(@board)) %>
<%= link_to('Delete', board_path(@board), method: :delete) %>
```

These actually render as the same URL but one will hit the `GET` route, the other the `DELETE` one.